Prove that $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^{2}+2X+2)$
$ S = \{\begin{pmatrix}x & y \\ -2y & x - 2y \end{pmatrix} \in M(2, \mathbb Q): x,y \in \mathbb Q\}$
Prove that $S \cong \mathbb Q[X]/(X^{2}+2X+2)$
I have already found that $S$ is a subring of $M(2, \mathbb Q)$.
Then I defined :
$\phi(a+bX):  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -2b & a-2b \end{pmatrix}$. I can show that this is a ringhomomorphism, so it is well defined. Is this the correct image I defined or is there a better way?

Your ring homomorphism is well defined. I gave you a more general solution that works for different matrix subalgebras

Set $A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$, we have $\chi_A = X(X+2)+2\cdot 1 = X^2 + 2X + 2$ and its is also its minimal polynomial since $A \notin \mathbb Q \cdot I_2$, therefore you have an isomorphism of rings given by the quotient of the following surjective ring morphism:
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\varphi: & \mathbb Q [X] &\to & \mathbb Q [A]\\
& X & \mapsto & A
\end{array}$$
This gives you since $\ker \varphi = \mu(A) \cdot \mathbb Q [X]$, where $\mu(A) = X^2+2X+2$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, an isomorphism
$$\bar\varphi: \mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+2X+2) \to \mathbb Q [A]$$
but $\mathbb Q [A]$ is a $\deg \mu(A) = 2$-dimensional $\mathbb Q$ vector space with basis $(I_2,A)$ thus $\mathbb Q[A] = S$.

Note that we have $ \varphi = \phi$ (the one in your post).
Your solution works perfectly but if you can recognise this pattern in higher dimension, you will avoid tedious computations.


May be it would be worth it to say that $\mu(A)$ is the minimal polynomial... it's not "obvious". (+1)

@Surb you mean precise the notation I use?
